# Finding SUSE registration status offline

Tags: sles

I have to find the registration status of SLES and SLED machines offline.

`SUSEConnect --status` requires internet connectivity to check the registration status.

`yast registration` module shows the registration status offline. But it uses GUI and doesn't support CLI interaction.

Older forum posts point to a file in `/var/cache/SuseRegister/`. But my SLES12 SP1 machine doesn't have that file even while being registered.